# Convert Perl to Shell

Tags: perl, shell

I have Perl script that I use to SNMP walk devices. However the server I have available to me does not allow me to install all the modules needed. So I need to convert the script to Shell (sh). I can run the script on individual devices but would like it to read from a text like it did in Perl. The Perl Script starts with:

```
 open(TEST, "cat test.txt |");
@records=<TEST>;
close(TEST);

foreach $line (@records)
                {
                ($field1, $field2, $field3)=split(/\s+/, $line);
                # Run and record SNMP walk results.
```

Comment: That script is incomplete and doesn't do anything.

Comment: You can probably install the modules along with the script, under your own account, but it can be tricky to get this right.

Comment: NB, that `open(TEST, "cat test.txt |")` is a pointless complication on what could be just `open(TEST, '<test.txt')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on exactly what the input is and what you are trying to do, that perl code fragment would likely translate to:

```
while read field1 field2 field3
do 
    # Run and record SNMP walk results.
    echo "1=$field1 2=$field2 3=$field3"
done <text.txt
```

For example, if `text.txt` is:

```
$ cat text.txt
one two three
i ii iii
```

Then, the above code produces the output:

```
1=one 2=two 3=three
1=i 2=ii 3=iii
```

As you can see, the shell `read` command reads a line (record) at a time and also does splitting on whitespace.  There are many options for `read` to control whether newlines or something else divide records (`-d`) and whether splitting is to be done on whitespace or something else (`IFS`) or whether backslashes in the input are to be treated as escape characters or not (`-r`).  See `man bash`.

Answer (score 0):

```
while read string; do
  str1=${string%% *}
  str3=${string##* }
  temp=${string#$str1 }
  str2=${temp%% *}
  echo $str1 $str2 $str3
done <test.txt
```

alternate version

```
while read string; do
  str1=${string%% *}
  temp=${string#$str1 }
  str2=${temp%% *}
  temp=${string#$str1 $str2 }
  str3=${temp%% *}
  echo $str1 $str2 $str3
done <test.txt
```

[POSIX substring parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02)

> ${parameter%word}
>
> Remove Smallest Suffix Pattern. The word shall be expanded to produce
>   a pattern. The parameter expansion shall then result in parameter,
>   with the smallest portion of the suffix matched by the pattern
>   deleted.
>
> ${parameter%%word}
>
> Remove Largest Suffix Pattern. The word shall be expanded to produce a
>   pattern. The parameter expansion shall then result in parameter, with
>   the largest portion of the suffix matched by the pattern deleted.
>
> ${parameter#word}
>
> Remove Smallest Prefix Pattern. The word shall be expanded to produce
>   a pattern. The parameter expansion shall then result in parameter,
>   with the smallest portion of the prefix matched by the pattern
>   deleted. ${parameter##word} Remove Largest Prefix Pattern. The word
>   shall be expanded to produce a pattern. The parameter expansion shall
>   then result in parameter, with the largest portion of the prefix
>   matched by the pattern deleted.
>
> ${parameter##word}
>
> Remove Largest Prefix Pattern. The word shall be expanded to produce a
>   pattern. The parameter expansion shall then result in parameter, with
>   the largest portion of the prefix matched by the pattern deleted.